# SLF4J MDC logging spring boot project included as dependency in other project not working

Tags: spring-boot, gradle, mdc

I have spring boot application A which has MDC logging is added as dependency in project B which also has MDC logging. Both works when they are run independently

Problem is : When I run the project B application, logs of B are displayed. I need the MDC logging parameters of A when A application code is invoke.

Example : MDC config of A application

     {
        "TransactionId":"111",
        "TransactionStatus":"started application A",
        "application" : "A"
      }

MDC config of B application

     {
        "TransactionId":"222",
        "TransactionStatus":"started application B",
        "application" : "B"
      }

When I run the B applcaiton I see logs as :
{"TransactionId":"222","TransactionStatus":"started application B","application":"B"}
{"TransactionId":"222","TransactionStatus":"started application B","application":"B"}

I need MDC logs to the displayed when application code A is invoked, which is included as part of gradle dependency in application B.

{"TransactionId":"222","TransactionStatus":"started application B","application":"B"}
{"TransactionId":"111","TransactionStatus":"started application A","application":"A"}

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is no applciation A when included in B, so how should that work?

Comment: @M. Deinum - application A is included as jar(added gradle dependency of A in application B) in B. 
When I invoke rest end point of B, it internally calls application A code. Then, I have to see MDC logs of A like :
{"TransactionId":"111","TransactionStatus":"started application A","application":"A", "message" : "message from A"}

currenlty I see logs as :
{"TransactionId":"222","TransactionStatus":"started application B","application":"B", "message" : "message from B"}
{"TransactionId":"222","TransactionStatus":"started application B","application":"B", "message" : "message from A"}

Comment: Again there is no application A. There is only application B if they both set the same MDC there is only the last one being set.

Comment: They have different values :

Application A - MDC config :
    <pattern>
         {
       "TransactionId":"111",
                        "TransactionStatus":"started application A",
                        "application" : "A"
                       }
                    </pattern>
Application B - MDC config :
    <pattern>
         {
       "TransactionId":"222",
                        "TransactionStatus":"started application B",
                        "application" : "B"
                       }
                    </pattern>


Thank you for your quick response.

Comment: I give up. There is only 1 applciation which happens to use classes from another application. They each write the same fields to the MDC so always the last value will remain. There is no application A or application B.